# Error when creation data source for neo4j in websphere application server

Tags: neo4j, websphere, datasource

Im trying to create data source for neo4j in websphere application server but its failing to connect. Any pointers on this would be helpful.

## JDBC Driver Created with the following parameters:

- Name : neo4j Driver
- Class path : path of the neo4j jdbc jar/neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.3.1.jar
- Implementation class name : org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver

## Data source created with the following :

- jndi Name: jdbc/neo4j

## Custom Properties:

- auth : container
- type: javax.sql.DataSource
- username: neo4j
- password: password
- url:jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:port
- removeAbandonedOnBorrow : true
- closeMethod : close

The properties are added based on the pointers provided in https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc

Here is the error from logs:

> java.lang.Exception: DSRA8101E: DataSource class cannot be used as
>   one-phase: ClassCastException: org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltDriver
>   incompatible with javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource [5/27/19
>   13:12:41:533 UTC] 00000111 SystemErr     R     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.createDataStoreAdapterException(AdapterUtil.java:441)
>   [5/27/19 13:12:41:533 UTC] 00000111 SystemErr     R     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigHelper.java:1340)

Answer (score 1):

According to its [documentation](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-jdbc/#_jdbc_compatibility)  Neo4j is NOT a compliant JDBC driver.

> We cover these aspects of the JDBC-APIs, everything that’s not
>   explicitely mentioned should be assumed to be not implemented

It also doesn't implement required javax.sql.DataSoruce interface, so it cannot be configured in the server. You will need to handle it in the application code.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify for others who may find this post in the future - whether or not it is possible to directly configure to java.sql.Driver depends on whether WebSphere Application Server traditional vs Liberty is being used.

A more indirect approach is possible in WebSphere Application Server traditional, which involves mocking up a ConnectionPoolDataSource class around the driver.  It is discussed under a [related stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330983/slowness-observed-in-obtaining-connection-using-neo4j-java-jdbc-driver).

With Liberty 18.0.0.3 and above, it is possible to directly configure a dataSource specifying only the URL, with examples given under [this knowledge center document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html).

Here is an example dataSource configuration in Liberty,

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
  ... other features
</featureManager>

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/neo4j" containerAuthDataRef="neo4jAuth">
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="neo4j"/>
  <properties URL="jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:7687"/>
</dataSource>

<authData id="neo4jAuth" user="neo4j" password="password"/>

<library>
  <file name="C:/drivers/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.3.1.jar"/>
</library>
```

Comment: The comment above about connections not being pooled is incorrect and based on a misunderstanding of the doc. There is a big difference between not providing connection pool enhancements vs not providing connection pooling at all. Liberty does indeed pool connections obtained via the Driver. However, some pooling enhancements are lacking, such as the javax.sql.ConnectionEventListener.connectionErrorOccurred mechanism by which the driver is able to notify the pool of bad connections. Even then, Liberty has other ways of detecting this, such as inspecting exception types, SQLStates & error codes